# Integration tests with Oracle Coherence

Tags: java, integration-testing, oracle-coherence

We have a set of integration tests, that use Oracle Coherence. All of them use the same config and the problem is that when you are running them in parallel, their coherence nodes join into one cluster and it is possible that one test affects others. Is there a simple way to prevent this joining? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We use [LittleGrid](http://www.littlegrid.org/) in our tests rather than start Coherence natively.  You can programmatically set up the grid and set the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For creating different clusters on a single machine for testing, you can use different tangosol-override config file.Just keep a tangosol-override file in the classpath of each cluster, provide different name to the clusters and specify different multi-cast address (not mandatory i guess). If you are using coherence 12C then you can also create different managed cluster in a single domain of weblogic server.

When you start a coherence node, it will read the tangosol-override file and issue multi-cast messages to the address mentioned in the file. When it doesn't find any other node or cluster with same cluster name. It starts it's own cluster as identifies itself as the master node.